# How to compile V8 alone and replace it for Chromium?

Tags: v8, chromium

I have compiled Chromium on Ubuntu. Now I want to modify the source code of V8 engine. But I don`t want to compile the whole Chromium because it consumes so much time. So how to compile V8 alone and replace it for Chromium? 
Thank you very much~

Answer (score 2):

If you edit V8's source within the Chromium checkout (in `<chromium>/src/v8/src`) and then recompile with `ninja -C out/Release chrome` (as you've probably compiled before), the build process will be smart enough to recompile only what's necessary.

One build step that takes considerable time is linking of the final binary. You can avoid that if you use a shared library build: run `gn args out/Release` and add a line `is_component_build = true`, then save and quit. On the *next* compile, that will cause *everything* to get recompiled, but on any further recompiles after that it will save time. (In Debug mode, you'll get a shared library build by default anyway.)